# What is the simplest way to fill web form with data from docx document?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webforms, docx

I want to automate some processes by letting user to choose docx document from local file system and then my script/application will insert data from document to a web form. That's all. There will be a couple of web forms and a couple of document types. What is the siplest way to do that and what technologies I need to look at first? What I was thinking at the moment is some google chrome extension with content scripts (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) + something like DOCX.js (http://blog.innovatejs.com/?p=184)..thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't really understand what you meant by "insert data from document to a web form", but here is a demo off docxtemplater, a library I maintain  on github that might do what you're seeking http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use content control data binding in your Word docx, then your data will be stored in XML format in a custom xml part.  That makes extracting it from the docx simple.

One other possibility for the other end is XForms.  If you are not commited to a particular web server yet, consider eXist, which ships with a couple of XForms implementations.

Then you have an end to end XML architecture (which might delight you or fill you with horror!).

Comment: I'm sorry for inaccuracy but by "there will be a couple of web forms" a meant that I want to use my application and my data with a couple of existing web forms on existing websites (which were done by other people). So workflow will be: user open website in browser, find form that he want to fill, and then use my application/chrome extension to fill fields in this form with data from docx document that he choose from local file system.